# Displaying part of number with brackets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

So I'm writing code for math assignment i have to represent number from variable the following way:
Let's say that's the number from variable A : 18,223443934844.
And that how it should print like : 18,223(443934844).
Numbers in the brackets are supposed to be the repeating part of the numbers after the decimal comma.

Had the idea to put every element of the number in array and then put the brackets whenever necessary but don't really know how to do it.

I'd appreciate every advice.

Comment: Probably just easiest to convert to string as normal then manipulate the strings

Comment: How do you know what the repeating part is?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Well I have the formula written and working. It's just presentation of the print that lacks

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you! I'll try something with that

Comment: How you present depends on what you have. What kind of result does your formula compute? Is it the start and the end position of the repeating part, or something else?

Comment: So I just converted everything to string and used .insert(); function. Thank you for the suggestions  <4